# How to annotate a corpus of written discourse for pragmatic analysis (speech acts)?

Tags: corpora, pragmatics

I am currently creating a small-ish corpus of online conversations that I wish to analyze quantitatively and qualitatively from a pragmatic perspective (speech acts level mainly). The problem is that I am stuck on how to go about linguistically annotating/ tagging it (it's my first time):
should I just add tags using a normal word-processor / text-editor or should I try to use an XML editor (and which)? Or is there some better way to go about it?

I am not familiar with XML but I have used LaTeX (if this is of any help?) and it seems that HTML or XML are nowadays more commonly used and favored for corpus annotating. On the other hand, I am only interested in quite simple pragmatic annotations for written language (which should be less complicated and demanding than annotating spoken discourse) so I don't know if using an unfamiliar medium is worth it.

Comment: Well, there's a number of tools. One popular one at the moment is Elan: [here's](https://tla.mpi.nl/tools/tla-tools/) the website where it (along with numerous other tools) may be found.

Comment: My previous comment assumed you want to annotate audio and/or video, but if you only have text data you could use [Toolbox](http://www-01.sil.org/computing/toolbox/) or [FLEx](http://fieldworks.sil.org/flex/).